# Time zone inconsistency in active admin csv download

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have been using active admin in my application and I set the time zone for every request based on the account. This has been working really well.

```
  #in initializer
  config.prepend_around_action :set_time_zone

  # in application controller
  def set_time_zone(&block)
    Time.use_zone(current_account.time_zone, &block)
  end
```

There is an inconsistency with the CSV downloads where both the filters and the time related fields use the application default time zone not the one set per request. Here is an example for the same record's :create_at

[image: created_at in csv]

[image]

This also then creats an inconsistency in the data set on the index page and the csv - if date related filters are applied.

Comment: Interesting.  I encourage you to submit this as an [issue on Github](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues).

Comment: Sure, thanks @PiersC, will do.